# How to Remove any row with "." in it?

Tags: r

In the following example, i want to remove any row with "." in the row names

```
data<-matrix(nrow=10,ncol=3,1)
 rownames(data)<-c("A.1","B.2",LETTERS[3:10])
```

I have tried grep like that:

```
data[( grepl(".", rownames(data))), ]
```

but, i think there is something missing here.
I will appreciate any help 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'.'` matches any character so needs escaping.

```
data <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=3,1)
rownames(data) <- c("A.1", "B.2", LETTERS[3:10])

data[!grepl('\\.', rownames(data)), ]

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
C    1    1    1
D    1    1    1
E    1    1    1
F    1    1    1
G    1    1    1
H    1    1    1
I    1    1    1
J    1    1    1
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the `fixed` argument: `grepl(pattern = ".", rownames(data), fixed = TRUE)`. "If TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is"

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
grep("[.]", x =rownames(data))
```

For example:

```
data[( grepl("[.]", rownames(data))), ]
```

This will return the rows containing "." in the names.

The problem with you approach is that the "." is a metacharacter. When you place it in square brackets it becomes regular character.